# php code to store id of selected value from autocomplete textbox

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

below is my autocomplete textbox code..

code is working fine..

**But I also need to store id of selected value in hidden textbox ..**

FOR EX =

there are 2 values coming in my auto textbox

```
id   societyname
7      raj
15     lucky
```

ok if i select raj from above value then display id of raj ie : 7 in hidden textbox

plz any one help me.

**Autocomplete textbox**

```
<input id="society_name" name="society"/>
 <input type="hidden" id="society_name" name="societyid"/>
```

**In ajax.php**

```
if($_GET['type'] == 'society'){ 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT society FROM societymaster where society LIKE '".strtoupper($_GET['name_startsWith'])."%'");  
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($data, $row['society']); 
    }   
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**auto.js**

```
$('#society_name').autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : 'ajax.php',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                           name_startsWith: request.term,
                           type: 'society'
                        },
                         success: function( data ) {
                             response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                                return {
                                    label: item,
                                    value: item
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                autoFocus: true,
                minLength: 0        
              });
```

Comment: always try to keep it simple and you cannot show hidden input value you can store values in it.

Comment: actually i need to store this id in database.

Answer (score 0):

Use the val() function on the input pass the id from the ajax results

```
$('#society_name').val(data.id);
```

**Updated code:**

php:

```
if($_GET['type'] == 'society'){ 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,society FROM societymaster where society LIKE '".strtoupper($_GET['name_startsWith'])."%'");  
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($data,$row); 
    }   
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

js:

```
  $('#society_name').autocomplete({
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url : 'ajax.php',
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {
                               name_startsWith: request.term,
                               type: 'society'
                            },
                             success: function( data ) {
                                $('#society_name').val(data[0].id);
                                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item,
                                        value: item
                                    }
                                }));
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    autoFocus: true,
                    minLength: 0        
                  });
```

Comment: when the success event is triggered see updated code

Comment: you want the id from the ajax results or other id?

Comment: i need to display name in autocomplete textbox but after selecting this display id of  ajax result..for ex - i post an example in my question...

Answer (score 0):

If you need IDs then fetch them from DB and return in ajax call (I guess this is the ID you are talking about).
From this point you can use something like this, that you cache the returned results in e.g. associative array:
$arr[value] = id;
and if user selects one of the values you can get the corresponding ID.
That's one method I guess.

BTW.
some tips for the future:
1. The id's fields should have unique values.
2. You should consider protecting your query from sql attacks. Here you do not even escape the string which is given by the user.
3. As far as I remember the mysql is obsolete so try to use mysqli instead.

**ajax.php**

```
if($_GET['type'] == 'society'){ 
    // try to switch to mysqli. You can also consider prepare statements.  
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, society FROM societymaster where society LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper($_GET['name_startsWith']))."%'");
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($data, $row); 
    }   
    // mysql_fetch_array returns indexed array so we should get JSON string like: "[['id1', 'value1'], ['id2', 'value2'], ...]"
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**.js file**

```
$.arr = [];
$('#society_name').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                name_startsWith: request.term,
                type: 'society'
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                // clear cache array and fill it with information about the new results (societies and corresponding ids)
                $.arr = [];
                $.each(data, function (idx, item) {
                    $.arr[item[1]] = item[0];
                });
                $('#society_name').val(data[0].id);
                response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item,
                        value: item
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 0        
});

// catch an event when the autocomplete closes and get id for selected society name
$("#tags").on("autocompleteclose", function() {
    // close event does not provide object data so we must fetch it again
    var selectedValue = $("#tags").val();
    var id = $.arr[selectedValue];
    // now you can set this ID as the value of your hidden input
});
```

Comment: yes you are right ...but i am new in ajax and i dont now how to return and display id plz help with code..

Comment: Ajax is a technique used for asynchronous communication with the server. What you do in ajax.js is just simple scripting with php.

Comment: If you want to get id from db then add the id before society "SELECT id, society FROM..." then you can push the whole row to the result array "array_push($data, $row)" you will then have a 2-dimentional array which will be encoded into JSON string

Comment: yes i created ajax.php file for database search and auto.js for handle request with javascript and ajax...

Comment: because you use fetch_array function I assume we will get output like this: "[['id1', 'society1'], ['id2', 'society2']...]" so on the js site you can modify your map function like this: 
$.map( data, function( item ) {
   return { 
      label: item[1],
      value: item[0]
}})
And then try to use the function from val() which madalin ivascu proposed (I'm not super familiar with autocomplete component so I must test it first before I will close this case :D )

Comment: ok I just played some with this autocomplete function and I was wrong in previous comment you have to have label and value the same "item[1]" in this case.